# Django thumbnails suggestion

Tags: django, django-models, django-imagekit

Looking for an alternate to django-imagekit.

django-imagekit with django-cumulus causes loads of timeout issues and makes apps very inconsistent.

Are there any alternatives that you can suggest that you have used in your previous projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy-thumbnails seem to be the de-facto standard these days

http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails

Comment: just tried out easy_thumbnails maybe 2 hours ago, seems to be a teething issue at the moment with some of their migrations in MySQL.

Comment: 1) When do migrations come into play at all? Why do you even care whether it has or does not have migrations?

Comment: 2) How is it in MySQL? They use south for migrations

Comment: They use south for migrations yes, well it seems that someone has setup in a different environment and now the source seems to fail around migration #10 - http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues#issue/45

Answer (score 3):

Well, [sorl](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/) was pretty good, but looks dead now. Maybe there's some actively developed fork somewhere.

Also, checkout [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/photos/), i'm sure you'll find useful code.